# "Sorry, your files couldn't be uploaded. The upload might be too large or the server might be experiencing high network traffic." uploading large file

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2016, document-upload

A site contributor reported not being able to upload larger pptx files to their site.
There is an Angular UI that interacts via SP2016 on-premise APIs. The user is seeing a continuous uploading message with no result.

Developer tools is showing: POST <%siteurl%> net::Err_FAILED 200 (OK)

When trying to upload the directly to a generic document library, it starts to upload but fails with the following error:
"Sorry, your files couldn't be uploaded. The upload might be too large or the server might be experiencing high network traffic."

File size is under 1 GB with the Central Administration > Web Application > General Settings set to allow up to 2 GB.  ULS logging does not indicate a specific error surrounding the transaction.

Tested in multiple browsers and in IE mode with the same results.
Reviewed similar questions posted here but no answers marked as successful.

Comment: Also tested the following possible solutions: https://www.vioreliftode.com/index.php/how-to-make-sharepoint-2016-not-fail-long-running-uploads-large-files/

https://www.koskila.net/sorry-your-files-couldnt-be-uploaded-the-upload-might-be-too-large-or-the-server-might-be-experiencing-high-network-traffic/

Answer (score 1):

Saw the same error across multiple sites but not in our lower environments. On a hunch, reached out to network team before opening a Microsoft ticket.

We narrowed down the cause to be a **network load balancer web application firewall policy** that was throwing a **Request length exceeds defined buffer size violation**.

Once the policy in violation was modified, the file was able to be uploaded with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue when trying to upload a 1GB document. My upload limit is 2GB per file. So I was able to resolve it by using Microsoft Edge in Internet Explorer mode. next, you must to clear browsing data: Select All time for Time range and keep the default selections. This made the trick.